# Usb comms intercepter

Tags: usb, man-in-the-middle

I have a question about intercepting and recording USB between two devices.  First, let me give y'all a bit of background.

I'm trying to connect a USB device, an Anritsu PSN50 power meter to my computer to collect power data that's coming in from a horn antenna I have set up, but alas the corporation that designed it did not build this functionality into it.  It communicates spendidly with the Anritsu VNA I have, the MS2036A, but alas the A series cannot relay that information back to my computer.  This is extremely upsetting, partially because the lead investigator was told this would be possible and paid $2000 bucks for it five years ago or so, and partially because I need this data for my own work.  I contacted the company about what to do but they told me to buy another, not useful at all.

The only way forward that I can see is to figure out a way to intercept the communications between the 2036A and the 50 to either figure out the command used to get the 50 going or to just tap directly into the data stream.  I realize this is going to be extremely tedious, but beyond that, how sound is this plan?  Is there any software packages that would allow me to plug my PC directly in between the two and listen?  I would rather not have to build a circuit for this, but if I must I will.  Thank you all for your time, and please have a nice day.

Surge

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Just google "USB protocol analyzer".

Comment: Hey dude, this would make the job tons easier, but those packaged devices are rather expensive, I don't have $400+ to fork out.

Comment: And even if you have the analyzer, then what? Extracting and decoding packetized communication between proprietary USB device with undisclosed control and calibration pipes and proprietary host application is not an easy feat.

Comment: That's very true.  I'm hoping my experience programming comms on other platforms will serve me well here.  The alternative is to spend $2500 on a new device, something I'm not ready to recommend to the rest of the team yet.

Comment: The USBproxy project is in Alpha (non-working) stage for 3 years now. You must have a USB analyzer to debug the tool first. You vasty under-estimate the task complexity. This not a $2,500 project, it is a $100,000 project, if reverce engineering is legal at all. Forget it and get the suggested equipment from Anritsu.

Comment: Sure, but I have to at least investigate it before I can make my recommendations to the lead investigator.  As far as the legality goes, who cares?

Comment: *"I don't have $400+ to fork out."* -- I don't know what your hourly rate is, but a purchased USB protocol analyzer or sniffer will probably cost less than my consulting rate to put together a SBC and USBproxy (e.g. the accepted answer).

Comment: So I just did the job with Wireshark, it turns out this would work for my purposes, thanks a lot for the guidance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good plan if you are confident in your ability to reverse engineer the protocol. It takes patience, a bit of experience and a lot of guessing and testing to do that.

To intercept, you need hardware that has both USB host and USB client (or OTG) ports, so a PC won't work. But you can use for example a cheap Beaglebone Black together with software like [usbproxy](https://github.com/dominicgs/USBProxy).

Comment: Beautiful, exactly the information I was looking for, thank you.